# File widget custom upload location

Tags: entities, hooks, files

I am working on a custom module (based on Model project) with a file field attached to my custom entities, now I would like to save files in certain directories according to entity id eg:

```
public://files/my_custom_entity_ID/filename
```

I've tried with `hook_file_insert` but can't get the entity id in order to use it later in `file_move`.

Which hook (if any) should I use? Or I am missing the whole approach?

Comment: Which version of Drupal? D7 or D8?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming D8

If this is part of a "BaseFieldDefinition" of your own entity, you may set a lot of options like so:

```
// create photo
$fields['photo'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('image')
    ->setLabel("Photo")
    ->setDescription('Ein Photo')
    ->setSettings(array(
        "file_directory" => 'profilbilder/[date:custom:Y]-[date:custom:m]',
        "file_extensions" => 'png gif jpg jpeg',
        "max_filesize" => '600 KB',
        "max_resolution" => '600x800',
        "min_resolution" => '30x40',
        "alt_field" => false,
        "alt_field_required" => false,
        "title_field" => false,
        "title_field_required" => false,
    ))
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'image_image',
        'weight' => 5,
    ))
    ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'type' => 'image',
        'weight' => 1,
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'settings' => array(
            'image_style' => 'thumbnail',
        ),
    ));
```

As you see, you can use tags in the file_directory setting.
If you craft your fields using the Drupal 8 field UI, you can also use tags in the UI field.

If it's D7, you should change to D8 :-)

Comment: It's still Drupal7